# Display the data of two xml codes in c# datagridview?

Tags: c#, xml

I have two xml codes that display the data from two seperate tables, now i want to read both of them in c# and display the data from join of them
I've tried this one but it just works for one table.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/ShowUsers.php");

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader input = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
           ds.ReadXml(input);
try
            {
                int varTotCol = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count, varTotRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                frm.dgv_ShowUsers.DataSource = ds.Tables["users"];
            }
            catch (Exception Except)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Except.ToString());
            }
```

And these are my xml codes:

```
 //first one
<users>
<ID>1</ID>
<user_login>admin</user_login> 
<user_pass>$P$Bdfdffddkjlkiyuyadnvjd</user_pass>
<term_id>2</term_id>
<user_activation_key></user_activation_key>
<user_status>0</user_status>
<display_name>admin</display_name>
<users>

//second one
<terms>
<term_id>2</term_id>
<name>name</name>
<term_group>0</term_group>
</terms>
```

I've convert my database to this xml code via php, I don't know if I should write it here too or not.
Now how should i change the c# code above to work for two or more tables?
Thanks beforehand and sorry for my english.

Comment: Usually reading a complex xml into a dataset produces a jagged array that is not easy to join.  It is better in these cases to write your own code to parse the xml into a single datatable.  I usually use xml linq in these cases.  I would need to see the xml to write the code.

Comment: When an XML file is read by a DataSet the root tag is the name of the dataset.  The 1st child tag is the name of the table(s).  The next level tags are the column names of the tables.  An finally the next level tag(s) is the actual data.  When the xml has more levels of nested tags additional data tables are created, but the primary keys of the additional tables are not organized very well to allow the tables to be joined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jdweng, i edited my post to contain xml code too.

Comment: You have one xml file so where are the two tables coming from?

Comment: I'm really sorry, i added second one right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml1 =
                "<root>" +
                "<users>" +
                    "<ID>1</ID>" +
                    "<user_login>admin</user_login>" +
                    "<user_pass>$P$Bdfdffddkjlkiyuyadnvjd</user_pass>" +
                    "<term_id>2</term_id>" +
                    "<user_activation_key></user_activation_key>" +
                    "<user_status>0</user_status>" +
                    "<display_name>admin</display_name>" +
                "</users>" +
                "</root>";

            XElement users = XElement.Parse(xml1);

            string xml2 =
                "<root>" +
                "<terms>" +
                    "<term_id>2</term_id>" +
                    "<name>name</name>" +
                    "<term_group>0</term_group>" +
                "</terms>" +
                "</root>";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Login", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Password", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TermID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Group", typeof(int));

            XElement terms = XElement.Parse(xml2);
            try
            {

                var groups = from user in users.Elements("users") 
                            join term in terms.Elements("terms")
                            on (int)user.Element("term_id") equals (int)term.Element("term_id")
                            select new { user = user, term = term };

                foreach (var group in groups)
                {

                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                       (int)group.user.Element("ID"),
                       (string)group.user.Element("user_login"),
                       (string)group.user.Element("user_pass"),
                       (int)group.user.Element("term_id"),
                       (string)group.user.Element("user_activation_key"),
                       (int)group.user.Element("user_status"),
                       (string)group.user.Element("display_name"),
                       (string)group.term.Element("Name"),
                       (int)group.term.Element("term_group")
                    });

                }
                frm.dgv_ShowUsers.DataSource = dt;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a dynamic solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml1Str =
                "<root>" +
                "<users>" +
                    "<ID>1</ID>" +
                    "<user_login>admin</user_login>" +
                    "<user_pass>$P$Bdfdffddkjlkiyuyadnvjd</user_pass>" +
                    "<term_id>2</term_id>" +
                    "<user_activation_key></user_activation_key>" +
                    "<user_status>0</user_status>" +
                    "<display_name>admin</display_name>" +
                "</users>" +
                "</root>";

            XElement xml1 = XElement.Parse(xml1Str);
            XElement xml1FirstNode = (XElement)xml1.FirstNode;
            string[] xml1ColNames = xml1FirstNode.Elements().Select(x => x.Name.LocalName).ToArray();

            string xml2Str =
                "<root>" +
                "<terms>" +
                    "<term_id>2</term_id>" +
                    "<name>name</name>" +
                    "<term_group>0</term_group>" +
                "</terms>" +
                "</root>";

            XElement xml2 = XElement.Parse(xml2Str);
            XElement xml2FirstNode = (XElement)xml2.FirstNode;
            string[] xml2ColNames = xml2FirstNode.Elements().Select(x => x.Name.LocalName).ToArray();


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string[] colNames = xml1ColNames.Union(xml2ColNames).ToArray();
            foreach (var colName in colNames)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(string));
            }

            try
            {

                var groups = from x1 in xml1.Elements()
                             join x2 in xml2.Elements()
                             on (string)x1.Element("term_id") equals (string)x2.Element("term_id")
                             select new { x1 = x1, x2 = x2 };

                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (var x1Value in group.x1.Elements())
                    {
                        newRow[x1Value.Name.LocalName] = (string)x1Value;
                    }
                    foreach (var x2Value in group.x2.Elements())
                    {
                        newRow[x2Value.Name.LocalName] = (string)x2Value;
                    }

                }
                frm.dgv_ShowUsers.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works itself but I want to load xml from a webpage and it'll be change every moment and can't be static. If I understand correctly this is static. What should i do for a dynamic one?

Comment: What is dynamic?  I want to make sure I understand you correctly.  Also what key is common between two tables?

Comment: I mean the xml files may change each time so i can't define them as a static string. I think there should be a way to read them from a webpage and use it in my program or maybe a way to change the value of the string base on the xml output of my webpage.

Comment: The commom field between tables is term_id

Comment: I added a dynamic solution.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't have any output.
And something else, I think I couldn't tell you what I mean, I meant I should read the xml for example every 10 minutes from a webpage(my real xml has 2000 users like what i wrote in my question) but here I have to put my xml in a string.

Comment: I left the output statement out : frm.dgv_ShowUsers.DataSource = dt;  The X.Element.Parse(string) method can take a string or you can use X,Element.Load(filename, URL or Stream).  The URL only works if the wepage is xml, otherwise, you have to have to use a Request() and extract the xlm from the request.

Comment: It works. Every thing is well. Thank you. Thank you.